# API Endpoint Authorization does not work via Powershell Script

Tags: rest, powershell, asp.net-core, jwt, bearer-token

I`m trying to write a simple script which is called by the task scheduler of my server via powershell.

The script looks like this.

```
$params = @{
    "username" = "name";
    "password" = "password";
}

$token = Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri "http://localhost:5000/api/login" -Body ($params|ConvertTo-Json) -ContentType "application/json"

echo $token //The token gets printed correctly

$headers = @{
    Authorization = "Bearer " +$token
}     

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri "http://localhost:5000/api/somemethod" -Headers $headers
```

The login gets called perfectly - the `somemethod` with the Annotation

```
[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
[HttpPost("somemethod/")]
public async Task<IActionResult> SomeMethod()
{
        //Do something
        return NoContent(); 
}
```

on the other hand gets the following console-output.

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST https:/localhost:5001/api//somemethod application/x-www-form-urlencoded 0
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[3]
      Route matched with {action = "SomeMethod", controller = "Api"}. Executing controller action with signature System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult] SomeMethod() on controller Api.Controllers.ApiController (Api).
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
      Authorization failed.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[3]
      Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult[1]
      Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes ().
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[12]
      AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was challenged.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
      Executed action Api.Controllers.ApiController.SomeMethod(Api) in 5.637ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 10.6572ms 401
```

What am i missing here?

Edit: When I debug into the middleware the Requests sends the token as expected. I will dig deeper into that and if needed come back with further informations.

[image]

Comment: Is `$token` in the correct format?  I assume the header expects a simple string (e.g. `Bearer 2c7d5601...`), but a lot of APIs will return the token in JSON format that you need to process before using.

Comment: The ```echo``` outputs the token as normal string so i think it is in the right format.

Comment: "Bearer was challenged" can mean the access token is fine but the principal (user) it represents doesn't have the correct access rights for the operation. Do you need to authenticate with a different username in order to use the somemethod endpoint?

Comment: No i do not. When i debug into my middleware i can see that the user gets authentificated but somehow it ends in a 401. I added an screen of the the request to the post. Could the error lead from the empty header-properties? When I try to add for example ```Connection = "Keep-Alive"``` the request doesn't even reach the Middleware.

Comment: If I call the API Endpoint via Postman everything works fine. It seems like the middleware for some reason interprets them differently

Answer (score 0):

I've seen lots of issues when `POST`ing and `content-type` hasn't been specified.

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri "http://localhost:5000/api/somemethod" -Headers $headers -Body $data -ContentType "application/json"
```

or whatever `content-type` you're `POST`ing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - there is no content added via body. The API Endpoint works as a trigger to remove inactive users from the application database. ```-ContentType "application/json"``` had no effect.